# I have a problem when I connect the application with firebase

Tags: android

[The first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ4F2.jpg)

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P1mN.jpg)

This message is the problem

Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.toshiba.myphone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
 testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

Can you help? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.toshiba.myphone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
 testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update gradle and firebase versions as required.

`'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'` Make it
`'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` Or anything that is compatible with your gradle.